# Wpf change xaml when object for binding changes

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to get from my database one item, and when clicking on the next or previous button, I would like to get the next item out of my database by increasing its ID. I'm at the point of having my first item in my card, but when I click on previous or next, nothing happens.
I have in xaml:

```
   <smtx:XamlDisplay Key="cards_1"  Margin="4 4 0 0">
            <materialDesign:Flipper Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignCardFlipper}">
                <materialDesign:Flipper.FrontContent>
                    <Grid Height="350" Width="200">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="250" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <materialDesign:ColorZone Mode="PrimaryMid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="AccountCircle" Height="128" Width="128"
                                                             VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </materialDesign:ColorZone>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentGebruiker.Naam}"></TextBlock>
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" Foreground="DarkGoldenrod"
                                            Command="{x:Static materialDesign:Flipper.FlipCommand}"
                                            Margin="0 4 0 0"
                                            >SHOW DETAILS</Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </materialDesign:Flipper.FrontContent>
```

And my viewmodel:

```
public ZoekMatchViewModel()
        {
            LeesGebruiker(1);
            KoppelenCommands();
        }

        private Gebruiker currentGebruiker;
        public Gebruiker CurrentGebruiker
        {
            get
            {
                return currentGebruiker;
            }

            set
            {
                currentGebruiker = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void KoppelenCommands()
        {
            NextCommand = new BaseCommand(VolgendeGebruiker);
            PrevCommand = new BaseCommand(VorigeGebruiker);
        }

        public ICommand NextCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand PrevCommand { get; set; }

        private void LeesGebruiker(int id)
        {
            //instantiëren dataservice
            ZoekMatchDataService zoekMatchDS =
                new ZoekMatchDataService();

            currentGebruiker = zoekMatchDS.GetGebruiker(id);
        }


        public void VolgendeGebruiker()
        {
            if (CurrentGebruiker != null)
            {
                int id = (currentGebruiker.ID) + 1;
                LeesGebruiker(id);
            }
        }


        public void VorigeGebruiker()
        {
            if (CurrentGebruiker != null)
            {
                int id = (currentGebruiker.ID) - 1;
                LeesGebruiker(id);
            }
        }
```

My buttons:

```
<Button Command="{Binding PrevCommand}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Height="50">
```

and

```
<Button Command="{Binding NextCommand}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Height="50">
```

So the problem is that my xaml doesn't update to the new user when I click on next or previous buttons.
If you need more information, I'm happy to provide!

Comment: Please, read [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and clarify your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "right" way to do this would be with a custom [`Selector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector). `Selector` is the base class used in WPF for a control that lets the user select one or more items from a list. For example: `ComboBox` and `ListBox` are both `Selector`s. If you've never made a custom control before this may be a bit complicated though.

There are a few simpler answers. You could make a class that holds all the data you want to display for a single option, and have your `Window` define a property of that type. Then you could bind all the variable parts of your interface to that property and just change the property value manually when the user clicks the left or right button. Of course you'd only be able to use this on one place, whereas if you made a custom control you could reuse it anywhere, any number of times.